# Text next to the table

Tags: longtable, landscape

I want to put text horizontally next to the table drawn using landscape and longtable packages. Currently text is being placed vertically as the table is. Following is my code

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\acmJournal{CSUR}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
%\begin{table}[ht]
\bgroup\tiny
    \begin{longtable}{ccccccc||ccccccc}
        \caption{Summary of Work}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Reference}                    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Intent Specification \& Translation}                                                                                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{Reference}                             & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Intent Specification \& Translation}                                                                                                         \\*
        \cline{2-7}\cline{9-14}
        &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}First\\Type\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Second\\Attributes\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Third\\Language\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fourth\\Processing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fifth\\Processing\\Method\end{tabular}& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sixth\\Language\end{tabular}   &    &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}First\\Type\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Second\\Attributes\end{tabular} &  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Third\\Language\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fourth\\Processing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fifth\\Processing\\Method\end{tabular}& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sixth\\Language\end{tabular} 
        \endfirsthead 

        \hline
        \cite{ROBOTRON}   & S, R     & OC, I/T, RR   & Pro   & C, D   & NG  & Pro.      & \cite{INSpIRE}   & B, S, R  & I/T, SA, EA   & CNL  & D & SG, ML & Pro.      \\ 
        \hdashline
        \cite{RCP}   & B, R     & OC, I/T, RR   & NEMO   & D   &     NG  & Pro.     & \cite{JANUS}   & B, S, R  & OC, SA, RR, TL, EA   & Pro.  & D & SG & Pro.      \\
        \hdashline
        \cite{LMS}   & S     & OC, EA   & Pro.   & D   &    SG   & Datalog      &  \cite{NLPSDN}   & B, S  & OC, I/T, SA, EA   & CNL  & D & NLP & NG       \\
        \hline
   \multicolumn{14}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{NG:} Not given, \textbf{B:} Business, \textbf{S:} Service, \textbf{R:} Resource, \textbf{I/T:} Instantiation/Termination,  \textbf{OC:} Object configuration \& modification, \textbf{SM:} Statistics monitoring, \textbf{RR:} Resource requirements, \textbf{SA:} Spatial arrangement \end{tabular}} \\  
        \multicolumn{14}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \textbf{TL:} Temporal limitations,  \textbf{MNL:} Monetary limitations, \textbf{EA:} Environment access/visibility, \textbf{T:} Translation, \textbf{C:} Completion,  \textbf{N:} Negotiation, \textbf{D:} Decomposition, \textbf{SG:} Semantic graphs, \textbf{GP:} Genetic Programming \end{tabular}}      \\
    \multicolumn{14}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \textbf{ML:} Machine learning, \textbf{Pro.:} Proprietary, \textbf{NLP:} Natural language processing, \textbf{DFA:} Deterministic finite automata, \textbf{CFG:} Context free grammar, \textbf{CNL:} Controlled natural language\end{tabular}}  
    \end{longtable}
%\end{table}
 \egroup

If you are preparing content for an event sponsored by ACM SIGGRAPH, you must use the "author year" style of citations and references. Uncommenting the next command will enable that style.

\end{landscape}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Place the text before rather than after `\end{landscape}`?

Comment: @Mico Just edited the question. I want to add the text horizontally. Text putting after \end{landscape} gets placed vertically.

Comment: Is the table supposed to span more than one page?

Comment: @egreg Yes, it spans to two pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I am not sure I like the effect, and of course it is only possible if the table leaves room on its last page, but:

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\acmJournal{CSUR}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
%\begin{table}[ht]
\bgroup\tiny
    \begin{longtable}{ccccccc||ccccccc}
        \caption{Summary of Work}\\
        \hline
        \multirow{2}{*}{Reference}                    & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Intent Specification \& Translation}                                                                                                        & \multirow{2}{*}{Reference}                             & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Intent Specification \& Translation}                                                                                                         \\*
        \cline{2-7}\cline{9-14}
        &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}First\\Type\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Second\\Attributes\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Third\\Language\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fourth\\Processing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fifth\\Processing\\Method\end{tabular}& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sixth\\Language\end{tabular}   &    &\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}First\\Type\end{tabular}  & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Second\\Attributes\end{tabular} &  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Third\\Language\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fourth\\Processing\end{tabular} & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Fifth\\Processing\\Method\end{tabular}& \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Sixth\\Language\end{tabular} 
        \endfirsthead 

        \hline
        \cite{ROBOTRON}   & S, R     & OC, I/T, RR   & Pro   & C, D   & NG  & Pro.      & \cite{INSpIRE}   & B, S, R  & I/T, SA, EA   & CNL  & D & SG, ML & Pro.      \\ 
        \hdashline
        \cite{RCP}   & B, R     & OC, I/T, RR   & NEMO   & D   &     NG  & Pro.     & \cite{JANUS}   & B, S, R  & OC, SA, RR, TL, EA   & Pro.  & D & SG & Pro.      \\
        \hdashline
        \cite{LMS}   & S     & OC, EA   & Pro.   & D   &    SG   & Datalog      &  \cite{NLPSDN}   & B, S  & OC, I/T, SA, EA   & CNL  & D & NLP & NG       \\
        \hline
   \multicolumn{14}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}\textbf{NG:} Not given, \textbf{B:} Business, \textbf{S:} Service, \textbf{R:} Resource, \textbf{I/T:} Instantiation/Termination,  \textbf{OC:} Object configuration \& modification, \textbf{SM:} Statistics monitoring, \textbf{RR:} Resource requirements, \textbf{SA:} Spatial arrangement \end{tabular}} \\  
        \multicolumn{14}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \textbf{TL:} Temporal limitations,  \textbf{MNL:} Monetary limitations, \textbf{EA:} Environment access/visibility, \textbf{T:} Translation, \textbf{C:} Completion,  \textbf{N:} Negotiation, \textbf{D:} Decomposition, \textbf{SG:} Semantic graphs, \textbf{GP:} Genetic Programming \end{tabular}}      \\
    \multicolumn{14}{l}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}} \textbf{ML:} Machine learning, \textbf{Pro.:} Proprietary, \textbf{NLP:} Natural language processing, \textbf{DFA:} Deterministic finite automata, \textbf{CFG:} Context free grammar, \textbf{CNL:} Controlled natural language\end{tabular}}  
    \end{longtable}
%\end{table}
 \egroup

 \begin{center}

\rotatebox{-90}{%
\parbox{8cm}{%
If you are preparing content for an event sponsored by ACM SIGGRAPH,
you must use the "author year" style of citations and
references. Uncommenting the next command will enable that style.}}
   
 \end{center}

\end{landscape}



\end{document}
```