# Continue table on next page

Tags: tables, captions, longtable, threeparttable, acm

Want to continue a table to the next page. Following is the code of the table

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\acmJournal{CSUR}
\usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{arydshln}
 \usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{lscape}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering  
\caption{Analysis of the research articles considered in this study by highlighting their strengths and weaknesses. }
\tiny
\label{table:9}
\begin{tabular}{cccccccccccc}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Authors}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Year}} &\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{IDSM Activities}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{Scale of Solution}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{\textbf{Area of Focus}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{Use of ML}}\\
    \cmidrule(r){3-6}\cmidrule(lr){7-8}\cmidrule(l){9-11}
&   & \textbf{A1} & \textbf{A2} & \textbf{A3} & \textbf{A4} & \textbf{SD} & \textbf{MD} & \textbf{Networks} & \textbf{Cloud computing} & \textbf{Blockchain} &\\ 
    \midrule
    Sung et al.\cite{ROBOTRON} & 2016 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Scheid et al.\cite{INSpIRE} & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Tsuzaki et al.\cite{RCP} & 2017 &\checkmark & & \checkmark& \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Abhashkumar et al.\cite{JANUS} & 2017 &\checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kang et al.\cite{LMS} & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \\
    Alsudais et al.\cite{NLPSDN} & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Sk{\"o}ldstr{\"o}m et al.\cite{DISMI} & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Liu et al.\cite{CPSFC}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Comer et al.\cite{OSDF}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Sanvito et al.\cite{IMR}  & 2018 & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Yang et al.\cite{Yang}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Elhabbash et al.\cite{MED}  & 2018 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Dzeparoska et al.\cite{ISDX}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Vilalta et al.\cite{ACSO}  & 2018 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \\
    Tuncer et al.\cite{HRLNBI}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Esposito et al.\cite{BDIS} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Chao et al.\cite{ICSM} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark\\
    Monga et al.\cite{SENSE} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kiran et al.\cite{iNDIRA} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Davoli et al.\cite{IoTSDN} & 2018 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Szyrkowiec et al.\cite{ACINO} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Wang et al.\cite{PHD1} & 2019 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Saraiya et al.\cite{PDNT} & 2019 & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Riftadi et al.\cite{GP4P4} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & & \checkmark  & & & \checkmark\\
        Wu et al.\cite{RDF} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & & & \checkmark  & & \\
    Riftadi et al.\cite{P4IO} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\        
    Aklamanu et al.\cite{OTTIBN} & 2019 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Borsatti et al.\cite{IBNFV} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Tian et al.\cite{JinJing} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & &\checkmark & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Kumar et al.\cite{GeoProtect} & 2019 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Chen et al.\cite{ComPress} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Chung et al.\cite{SDX} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Jacobs et al.\cite{REFINE} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark  & & & \checkmark\\
    Scheid et al.\cite{BC} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark &\\
    Khan et al.\cite{GIBN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Chung et al.\cite{IoTD} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Ujcich et al.\cite{PIBN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Alalmaei et al.\cite{SDNHN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & &\checkmark & & \\
    Mahtout et al.\cite{EVIAN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Nagendra et al.\cite{VISCR} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Gao et al.\cite{ANIM} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Shi et al.\cite{SCOIBT} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Ribeiro et al.\cite{SCRIBE} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Nazarzadeoghaz et al.\cite{ADNS} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kim et al.\cite{IBCS} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \\
    Wang et al.\cite{LocJury} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Marsico et al.\cite{AGF} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Rafiq et al.\cite{SPM} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Mehmood et al.\cite{EEAS} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & \checkmark & & &\\
    Yang et al.\cite{IDON} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & &\checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Zhang et al. \cite{QICR} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Wu et al. \cite{Yuming} & 2021 &  & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Gritli et al. \cite{Nour} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & &  &\checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Mehmood et al. \cite{Kashif} & 2021 & \checkmark &\checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Khan et al. \cite{IKOREN} & 2021 & \checkmark &\checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Mercian et al. \cite{PII} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Zheng et al. \cite{Zheng} & 2021 & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Bensalem et al. \cite{SCN} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Bezahaf et al. \cite{TAIP} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Ouyang et al. \cite{RIDN} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Dzeparoska et al. \cite{TSDMS} & 2021 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & &\\
    Abbas et al. \cite{NSLCM} & 2021 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & &\checkmark\\        
    el houda Nouar et al. \cite{VIKING} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kuwahara et al. \cite{IBSCD} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\     
    de Sousa et al. \cite{SMM} & 2021 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Jacobs et al. \cite{LUMI} & 2021 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Gomes et al. \cite{Gomes} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Curtis-Black et al. \cite{PHD2} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
        Collet et al. \cite{LossLeap} & 2022 & & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
        McNamara et al. \cite{FIIR} & 2022 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        He et al. \cite{VECIBN} & 2022 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Fern{\'a}ndez et al. \cite{SON2} & 2022 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Kuroda et al. \cite{DX} & 2022 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
        Ustok et al. \cite{AAS} & 2022 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
        Karrakchou et al. \cite{I2DN} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Banerjee et al. \cite{ICDR} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\begin{tablenotes}
\tiny
\item \textbf{A1:} Activity 1 (specification and translation); \textbf{A2:} Activity 2 (deployment and orchestration); \textbf{A3:} Activity 3 (Monitoring and awareness); \textbf{A4:} Activity 4 (optimization and remediation); \textbf{SD: } S domain; \textbf{MD: } M Domain; \textbf{ML: } Learning
\end{tablenotes}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The  `acmart` doesn't enable to split tables across the pages.

Comment: @Zarko No, it does. I have other tables with different formats  which are spanned. However, I couldn't span this table while retaining its structure.

Comment: You may be right. I just cite what is in instruction for `acmart` document class. I can't verified this since my local installation of amcart is broken. Than try just to remove  `table` environment and use `longtable`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you issue the instruction `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.91}` immediately before `\begin{tabular}`, and if you shorten the caption so that it fits on a single line, you can get the whole table, including the legend, to fit on a single page.

The framelines in the following screenshot are drawn courtesy of the `showframe` package.

[image]

Aside: I can see no good reason for using **bold-facing** in the header and the legend.

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\acmJournal{CSUR}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\let\cm\checkmark % handy shortcut macro

\usepackage{showframe} % optional
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[p]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Analysis of research articles, with highlights of their strengths and weaknesses.}
\label{table:9}
\centering  
\tiny
\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.91} % <-- new
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{11}{c} @{}}
\toprule
Authors & Year
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{IDSM Activities} 
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Scale} 
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{Area of Focus} 
& Use of ML\\
\cmidrule(lr){3-6} \cmidrule(lr){7-8} \cmidrule(l){9-11}
& & A1 & A2 & A3 & A4 & SD & MD
  & Networks & Cloud computing & Blockchain \\ 
\midrule
    Sung et al.\cite{ROBOTRON} & 2016 & \cm & & \cm & \cm & \cm & & \cm \\
    Scheid et al.\cite{INSpIRE} & 2017 &\cm & & & & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm\\
    Tsuzaki et al.\cite{RCP} & 2017 &\cm & & \cm& \cm & & \cm & \cm \\
    Abhashkumar et al.\cite{JANUS} & 2017 &\cm & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Kang et al.\cite{LMS} & 2017 &\cm & & & & \cm & & & \cm \\
    Alsudais et al.\cite{NLPSDN} & 2017 &\cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Sköldström et al.\cite{DISMI} & 2017 &\cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Liu et al.\cite{CPSFC}  & 2018 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm & & & \cm\\
    Comer et al.\cite{OSDF}  & 2018 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Sanvito et al.\cite{IMR}  & 2018 & & & \cm & \cm & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm \\
    Yang et al.\cite{Yang}  & 2018 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Elhabbash et al.\cite{MED}  & 2018 & \cm & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Dzeparoska et al.\cite{ISDX}  & 2018 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Vilalta et al.\cite{ACSO}  & 2018 & \cm & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Tuncer et al.\cite{HRLNBI}  & 2018 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Esposito et al.\cite{BDIS} & 2018 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Chao et al.\cite{ICSM} & 2018 & \cm & & & & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm\\
    Monga et al.\cite{SENSE} & 2018 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Kiran et al.\cite{iNDIRA} & 2018 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Davoli et al.\cite{IoTSDN} & 2018 & \cm & & \cm & \cm  & & \cm & \cm \\
    Szyrkowiec et al.\cite{ACINO} & 2018 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Wang et al.\cite{PHD1} & 2019 & \cm & & \cm & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Saraiya et al.\cite{PDNT} & 2019 & & & \cm & \cm & \cm & & \cm \\
    Riftadi et al.\cite{GP4P4} & 2019 & \cm & & & &\cm & & \cm  & & & \cm\\
    Wu et al.\cite{RDF} & 2019 & \cm & & & &\cm & & & \cm  \\
    Riftadi et al.\cite{P4IO} & 2019 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\        
    Aklamanu et al.\cite{OTTIBN} & 2019 & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm & \cm  & & &\\
    Borsatti et al.\cite{IBNFV} & 2019 & \cm & & & &\cm & & \cm  & & &\\
    Tian et al.\cite{JinJing} & 2019 & \cm & & & & &\cm & \cm  & & &\\
    Kumar et al.\cite{GeoProtect} & 2019 & \cm & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm  & & &\\
    Chen et al.\cite{ComPress} & 2019 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm  & & &\\
    Chung et al.\cite{SDX} & 2019 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm  & & &\\
    Jacobs et al.\cite{REFINE} & 2019 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm  & & & \cm\\
    Scheid et al.\cite{BC} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & & & \cm &\\
    Khan et al.\cite{GIBN} & 2020 & \cm & & \cm & \cm & & \cm & \cm & & & \cm\\
    Chung et al.\cite{IoTD} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm & & &\\
    Ujcich et al.\cite{PIBN} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm & & &\\
    Alalmaei et al.\cite{SDNHN} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & &\cm \\
    Mahtout et al.\cite{EVIAN} & 2020 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm & & & \cm\\
    Nagendra et al.\cite{VISCR} & 2020 & \cm & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Gao et al.\cite{ANIM} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Shi et al.\cite{SCOIBT} & 2020 & \cm & \cm & & & & \cm & \cm & & & \cm\\
    Ribeiro et al.\cite{SCRIBE} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Nazarzadeoghaz et al.\cite{ADNS} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Kim et al.\cite{IBCS} & 2020 & \cm & & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Wang et al.\cite{LocJury} & 2020 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm & & &\\
    Marsico et al.\cite{AGF} & 2020 & \cm & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm & & &\\
    Rafiq et al.\cite{SPM} & 2020 & \cm & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm & & &\\
    Mehmood et al.\cite{EEAS} & 2020 & \cm & \cm & & & &\cm & \cm & & &\\
    Yang et al.\cite{IDON} & 2020 & \cm & \cm & \cm & \cm & &\cm & \cm & & & \cm\\
    Zhang et al. \cite{QICR} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Wu et al. \cite{Yuming} & 2021 &  & & \cm & & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm \\
    Gritli et al. \cite{Nour} & 2021 & \cm & & & &  &\cm & \cm \\
    Mehmood et al. \cite{Kashif} & 2021 & \cm &\cm & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Khan et al. \cite{IKOREN} & 2021 & \cm &\cm & \cm & & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm \\
    Mercian et al. \cite{PII} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Zheng et al. \cite{Zheng} & 2021 & & & & \cm & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm \\
    Bensalem et al. \cite{SCN} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Bezahaf et al. \cite{TAIP} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Ouyang et al. \cite{RIDN} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Dzeparoska et al. \cite{TSDMS} & 2021 & \cm & & \cm & \cm &  & \cm & \cm & & &\\
    Abbas et al. \cite{NSLCM} & 2021 & \cm & & \cm & \cm &  & \cm & \cm & & &\cm\\        
    el houda Nouar et al. \cite{VIKING} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Kuwahara et al. \cite{IBSCD} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\     
    de Sousa et al. \cite{SMM} & 2021 & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Jacobs et al. \cite{LUMI} & 2021 & \cm & \cm & & & \cm &  & \cm & & & \cm \\
    Gomes et al. \cite{Gomes} & 2021 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Curtis-Black et al. \cite{PHD2} & 2021 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Collet et al. \cite{LossLeap} & 2022 & & & \cm & & & \cm & \cm & & & \cm \\
    McNamara et al. \cite{FIIR} & 2022 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    He et al. \cite{VECIBN} & 2022 & \cm & \cm & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Fern{\'a}ndez et al. \cite{SON2} & 2022 & \cm & & \cm & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Kuroda et al. \cite{DX} & 2022 & \cm & & & & & \cm & \cm & & & \cm \\
    Ustok et al. \cite{AAS} & 2022 & \cm & & \cm & & & \cm & \cm \\
    Karrakchou et al. \cite{I2DN} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
    Banerjee et al. \cite{ICDR} & 2021 & \cm & & & & \cm & & \cm \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[]
A1: Specification and translation; 
A2: Deployment and orchestration; 
A3: Monitoring and awareness; 
A4: Optimization and remediation; \newline
SD: S domain; MD: M Domain; ML: Machine Learning
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Any opinion on the following question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676430/text-next-to-the-table

Comment: @YogeshSharma - I'm afraid not, except to note that it still isn't clear to me that you mean by "horizontally" and "vertically". Very sorry. (It may, or may not, help if you used the terms "landscape orientation" and "portrait orientation".)

Comment: @YogeshSharma - A suggestion about the table above: As the areas "Network", "Cloud computing", and "Blockchain" appear to be mutually exclusive, and since there's just 1 article in the "Blockchain" category, it may be easier on your readers if you created two, smaller tables: A first, longer one about articles with "network" focus, and a second, shorter one about articles with cloud computing focus. If that's too much extra work, you might at least consider reorganizing the table so that it first lists all articles with a network focus, then all articles with a cloud focus, etc.

Comment: @Micro Thank you for the suggestion. However, articles are sorted year wise and analysis is backed by various pie charts. Application of your suggestion will cause signification changes in the manuscript.

Comment: @YogeshSharma - Fair enough. I had noticed that the articles were organized by year -- except, for some reason, the final two -- but wasn't aware that this sorting choice was backed by further analysis.

Comment: Moreover this is not a complete list of articles. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143161/discussion-between-yogesh-sharma-and-mico).

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (tested on Overleaf):

```
\documentclass[acmsmall]{acmart}
\acmJournal{CSUR}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begingroup
   \footnotesize
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {Analysis of the research articles considered in this study by highlighting their strengths and weaknesses.},
  label = {table:9},
remark{Note} = {\textbf{A1:} Activity 1 (specification and translation); 
            \textbf{A2:} Activity 2 (deployment and orchestration); 
            \textbf{A3:} Activity 3 (Monitoring and awareness); 
            \textbf{A4:} Activity 4 (optimization and remediation); 
            \textbf{SD:} S domain; 
            \textbf{MD:} M Domain; 
            \textbf{ML:} M Learning;
            \textbf{NW:} Network;
            \textbf{CC:} Cloud computing;
            \textbf{BC:} Blockchain}
                ]{colspec = {@{} ll *{10}{X[c]} @{}},
                  rowsep = 0pt,
                  row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
                  row{odd[5]} = {abovesep=1ex},
                  rowhead=2
                  }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Authors 
    &   \SetCell[r=2]{l}    Year    
        &   \SetCell[c=4]{c}    {IDSM\\ Activities}
            &   &   &   &   \SetCell[c=2]{c}    {Scale of\\ Solution}
                            &   &   \SetCell[c=3]{c}    {Area of\\ Focus}
                                    &   &   &   \SetCell[r=2]{c}    {Use of ML}   
                                                \\
    \cmidrule[r]{3-6}
    \cmidrule[lr]{7-8}
    \cmidrule[l]{9-11}
    &   &    A1
            &   A2
                &   A3
                    &   A4
                        &   SD
                            &   MD
                                &   NW
                                    &   CC
                                        &   BC
                                            &       \\
    \midrule
Sung et al.\cite{ROBOTRON} 
    & 2016 
        &   \checkmark 
            &   &   \checkmark 
                    &   \checkmark 
                        &   \checkmark 
                            &   &   \checkmark 
                                    &   &   &                               \\
Scheid et al.\cite{INSpIRE} 
    & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
Tsuzaki et al.\cite{RCP} 
    & 2017 &\checkmark & & \checkmark& \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Abhashkumar et al.\cite{JANUS} & 2017 &\checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kang et al.\cite{LMS} & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \\
    Alsudais et al.\cite{NLPSDN} & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Sk{\"o}ldstr{\"o}m et al.\cite{DISMI} & 2017 &\checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Liu et al.\cite{CPSFC}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Comer et al.\cite{OSDF}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Sanvito et al.\cite{IMR}  & 2018 & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Yang et al.\cite{Yang}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Elhabbash et al.\cite{MED}  & 2018 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Dzeparoska et al.\cite{ISDX}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Vilalta et al.\cite{ACSO}  & 2018 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \\
    Tuncer et al.\cite{HRLNBI}  & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Esposito et al.\cite{BDIS} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Chao et al.\cite{ICSM} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark\\
    Monga et al.\cite{SENSE} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kiran et al.\cite{iNDIRA} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Davoli et al.\cite{IoTSDN} & 2018 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Szyrkowiec et al.\cite{ACINO} & 2018 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Wang et al.\cite{PHD1} & 2019 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Saraiya et al.\cite{PDNT} & 2019 & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Riftadi et al.\cite{GP4P4} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & & \checkmark  & & & \checkmark\\
        Wu et al.\cite{RDF} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & & & \checkmark  & & \\
    Riftadi et al.\cite{P4IO} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Aklamanu et al.\cite{OTTIBN} & 2019 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Borsatti et al.\cite{IBNFV} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Tian et al.\cite{JinJing} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & &\checkmark & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Kumar et al.\cite{GeoProtect} & 2019 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Chen et al.\cite{ComPress} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Chung et al.\cite{SDX} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark  & & &\\
    Jacobs et al.\cite{REFINE} & 2019 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark  & & & \checkmark\\
    Scheid et al.\cite{BC} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark &\\
    Khan et al.\cite{GIBN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Chung et al.\cite{IoTD} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Ujcich et al.\cite{PIBN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Alalmaei et al.\cite{SDNHN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & &\checkmark & & \\
    Mahtout et al.\cite{EVIAN} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Nagendra et al.\cite{VISCR} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Gao et al.\cite{ANIM} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Shi et al.\cite{SCOIBT} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Ribeiro et al.\cite{SCRIBE} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Nazarzadeoghaz et al.\cite{ADNS} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kim et al.\cite{IBCS} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \\
    Wang et al.\cite{LocJury} & 2020 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Marsico et al.\cite{AGF} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Rafiq et al.\cite{SPM} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & &\\
    Mehmood et al.\cite{EEAS} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & &\checkmark & \checkmark & & &\\
    Yang et al.\cite{IDON} & 2020 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark & &\checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark\\
    Zhang et al. \cite{QICR} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Wu et al. \cite{Yuming} & 2021 &  & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Gritli et al. \cite{Nour} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & &  &\checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Mehmood et al. \cite{Kashif} & 2021 & \checkmark &\checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Khan et al. \cite{IKOREN} & 2021 & \checkmark &\checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Mercian et al. \cite{PII} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Zheng et al. \cite{Zheng} & 2021 & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Bensalem et al. \cite{SCN} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Bezahaf et al. \cite{TAIP} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Ouyang et al. \cite{RIDN} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Dzeparoska et al. \cite{TSDMS} & 2021 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & &\\
    Abbas et al. \cite{NSLCM} & 2021 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & \checkmark & & &\checkmark\\
    el houda Nouar et al. \cite{VIKING} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    Kuwahara et al. \cite{IBSCD} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    de Sousa et al. \cite{SMM} & 2021 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Jacobs et al. \cite{LUMI} & 2021 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark &  & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
    Gomes et al. \cite{Gomes} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
    Curtis-Black et al. \cite{PHD2} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
        Collet et al. \cite{LossLeap} & 2022 & & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
        McNamara et al. \cite{FIIR} & 2022 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        He et al. \cite{VECIBN} & 2022 & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Fern{\'a}ndez et al. \cite{SON2} & 2022 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Kuroda et al. \cite{DX} & 2022 & \checkmark & & & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \checkmark \\
        Ustok et al. \cite{AAS} & 2022 & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \checkmark & \checkmark & & & \\
        Karrakchou et al. \cite{I2DN} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
        Banerjee et al. \cite{ICDR} & 2021 & \checkmark & & & & \checkmark & & \checkmark & & & \\
    \bottomrule
\end{longtblr}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]